# What is the limit of $\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2+\ln n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

is it equal to infinity because $$2^n+n^2+\ln n \approx~2^n?$$
Thanks

Comment: Ant thus $\sqrt[n]{...}\approx 2.$

Comment: Hint: What does $\sqrt[n]{2^n}$ equal?

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in [what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are](http://goo.gl/mLWc8); this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help. To prevent that, please [edit] the question and refer to [How to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: write your term in the form $$2\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{n^2}{2^{n}}+\frac{\ln(n)}{2^n}}$$

Answer (score 2):

(I assume you're taking the limit as $n\to\infty$)

Hint: As $n$ grows large, how to the $n^2$ and $\ln n$ terms compare to $2^n$?

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, $2^n+n^2+\ln n \sim2^n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. In particular, observe that for sufficiently large $n$ (can take $n\geqslant4$) we have the inequality $$2^{n}\leqslant 2^n+n^2+\ln n \leqslant 2^{n} + 2^{n} +2^{n}.$$
Taking $n$ th roots gives $$2\leqslant \sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2+\ln n} \leqslant 2\sqrt[n]{3}.$$
Now using the fact that $\sqrt[n]{3}\rightarrow1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we can apply the squeeze theorem and conclude that $\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2+\ln n}\rightarrow 2$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is $2$.

$$L=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} 2\left((1+\frac{1}{\frac{2^n}{n^2+\ln 2}})^{\frac{2^n}{n^2+\ln 2}}\right)^{\frac{n(n^2+\ln 2)}{2^n}}=2\cdot e^0=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $n^2+\ln n<n^2+n=n(n+1)<2^n$ if $n\geq 5$ (Check it by induction, use $n+1<2^{n-1}$ if $n\geq 5$(or you can prove that too by induction)).

Then $$2^n<2^n+n^2+\ln n <2^{n+1}\\\Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{2^n}<\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2+\ln n} <\sqrt[n]{2^{n+1}}$$

Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2=2<\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2+\ln n} <\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{n+1}{n}}=2$$

Then by squeeze theorem $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2+\ln n}=2\space\space\space\blacksquare$$